# Out of the box, SpecFlow is giving me a generation error

Tags: visual-studio, specflow, xunit

Google isn't turning up much for me. Here's the error in the feature.cs file:

```
#error Generation error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here's the setup:

VS2017, XUnit, Specflow.XUnit, xunit.runner.visualstudio (and all dependent packages), mvc site. All packages, etc updated.

Add a feature file (named SpecFlowFeature1.feature).

Right click feature file and click Generate Step Definitions.

SpecFlowFeature1.feature.cs has the error.

Why is it doing this and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Is the feature file empty?

Comment: No, it's "out of the box" meaning it has the default feature and scenario definition (the calculator app)

Comment: Ok, that's strange. Could you file an issue at https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow and attach your project? I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is solved.

SpecFlow was added to the web- project and not in a separate unit test project.